# How to obtain the corresponding type for each key

Tags: typescript

Enter the key to obtain the corresponding type in getType

```
declare function func<T1 extends string = string>(service: {
  list: { key?: T1; getType?: (data: T1) => void }[];
}): void;

export const d = func({
  list: [
    { key: 'a', getType: data => data }, // result is `a|b`,i want `a`
    { key: 'b', getType: data => data }, // result is `a|b`,i want `b`
  ],
});
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NVlonW) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.6#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCpwEYBsIAUoD2ADgM4A8qyAvMgEoQIFQAmZJYUoA5gDTJwgAngD5hyAN4AoZMkZYArgFsQJAFwTkzOGDgBJEMwgAPAPzqA1hEEEYaANzIoEA9DPIAFADc4CiBas2aACU1GKeBMDMyAC+ANoAunaS0ZKSxkRMYLIEKllaOuro2HiEpGTi-OrsnCBcDhjqIEoY0DFiNFIyckoq6rHSMhr5ei5G6gDkcON8Ti5Q6t6+ociL8ijRfMgA9FuOECTyWFnAJMgABnAAPhhnPMDIAO4CWRdnAzIVw-qGY8jjGNM9nMFj41stVutNjs9gcjsgTucrjc7o9nucbgN4jxkkkgA